# How to develop a button for followers of a web site

Tags: web-services, button, web, social-networking

I apologize for my English it is not very good.

I am developing a website that will have own followers.

I need to create a button by followers such as facebook, twitter or google plus buttons.

Thank you for any information that will allow me to begin to develop the button next to the platform.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, your English is fair enough. For creating your own follow button you will have to have an image that will be displayed on your website. When someone clicks on that button, your webapp should be able to know who clicked it and your should be able to remember that user in future as well. So first you will have users to register on your website (like facebook and twitter) for unique identification of each user.

Next, for remembering that a particular user is following your website you need to persist some information about that user. The obvious approach is having a database table to store the information. For instance you can have `IS_FOLLOWING` column in your `USER` table

But there are some considerations. First, the user must remain on the same page or be able to continue his activity even after cicking the follow button. For example, if the user is filling some form then his data should remain intact even after clicking the `follow` button. If the user is directed to some other page, he might lose information.

Second, database operations are costly. So you need to use them wisely.

One approach that I could think of is having AJAX do the work. If you want to learn AJAX you can visit [this website](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP) and for AJAX database operations [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm) will be helpful.

Ajax will do all the work in background and both the problems mentioned above will be addressed. I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your initial support.

I am developing web site in Python / Django. I'm going to investigate a little more on the use of Ajax to implement the button.